# Ruby - Files - gets method

Tags: ruby

I am following Wicked cool ruby scripts book. 
here,
there are two files, file_output = file_list.txt and oldfile_output = file_list.old. These two files contain list of all files the program went through and going to go through. 
Now, the file is renamed as old file if a 'file_list.txt' file exists .
then, I am not able to understand the code.

Apparently every line of the file is read and the line is stored in oldfile hash. 
Can some one explain from 4 the line?

And also, why is gets used here? why cant a .each method be used to read through every line?

```
if File.exists?(file_output)
  File.rename(file_output, oldfile_output)
  File.open(oldfile_output, 'rb') do |infile|
  while (temp = infile.gets)
    line = /(.+)\s{5,5}(\w{32,32})/.match(temp)
    puts "#{line[1]} ---> #{line[2]}"
    oldfile_hash[line[1]] = line[2]
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: what does the 5th line do here?

Comment: This script is pretty much the exact opposite of Wicked Cool. It's horrible.

Comment: Okay, thats bad! could you answer to the comment below please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from the redundant use of quantifiers (`{5,5}` and `{32,32}`) in the regex (which would be better written as `{5}`, `{32}`), it looks like the person who wrote that code is not a professional Ruby programmer. So you can assume that the choice taken in the code is not necessarily the best.

As you pointed out, the code could have used `each` instead of `while` with `gets`. The latter approach is sort of an old-school Ruby way of doing it. There is nothing wrong in using it. Until the end of file is reached, `gets` will return a string, and when it does reach the end of file, `gets` will return `nil`, so the `while` loop works as the same when you use `each`; in each iteration, it reads the next line.

It looks like each line is supposed to represent a key-value pair. The regex assumes that the key is not an empty string, and that the key and the value are separated by exactly five spaces, and the the value consists of exactly thirty-two letters. Each key-value pair is printed (perhaps for monitoring the progress), and is stored in `oldfile_hash`, which is most likely a hash.

Comment: key-value? All i get is a list of file(with path) and a huge 32 letter value. If I change the s{} and w{} and run the script again, I am getting the same output

Comment: it also does not get printed. and how does the `oldfile_hash = line[1] = line[2] ` store the value to the hash?

Comment: To run through the program real quick, The script runs first, the list of all the files are included with a MD5 hash into file_list.txt. then when the script runs again the file_list.txt is renamed to file_list.old and new file_list.txt is created. 
Now the file_list.old ones taken, teach line is matched with a pattern? then added to hash? Could you explain the pattern?

Inside the file_list.old ,the format is
`/dir/dir/dir/file.rb   a4434343f3f3f3f3r3343434343ftj6a`

Answer (score 0):

So the point of using .gets is to tell when the file is finished being read. Essentially, it's tied to the

```
while (condition)
      ....
end
```

block. So gets serves as a little method that will keep giving ruby the next line of the file until there is no more lines to give.